# how to change Gridview row color permnetly after Editing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one grid view in that i have item template called link button by clicking on that link button Ajax popup extender will appear and user Edits the items.. After editing the Row Color should Change to some other color.. Colors should Change Permanently.. How Can i Achieve this

Thanks

Comment: you will need to save some information in your database to tell ASP that this row has been edited if you want to change its color permanently. An example of the column name would be [EDITED] and if its value is TRUE/YES than let that event that handles populating its content to change the color of the row depending on the value of the EDITED column

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it by setting the Rows BackColor in the GridViews RowUpdated Event

```
Example:

<asp:gridview id="gridView1" 
        onrowupdated="gridView1_RowUpdated"   
        runat="server"
       ...........................

protected void gridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gridView1_RowUpdated.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    row.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
}
```